# Unexpected TICK error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to write a VHDL module but I have a problem with the if statement. Most probably it is a silly mistake, but since I am very new to VHDL, I could not figure out the problem. Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity binary_add is
    port( n1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    n2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    segments : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    bool : out bit;
    o : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    DNout : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));

end binary_add;

architecture Behavioral of binary_add is
begin

process(n1, n2) 
begin

o <= n1 + n2;

if( o = '1010') then 
bool <= '1';
else
bool <= '0';
end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

And I get the following answer from the first line of if statement:

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:## - "C:/Xilinx/12.3/ISE_DS/ISE/.../binary_add.vhd" Line ##. parse error, unexpected TICK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. If an answer helped you out, please upvote. Accept the most useful!

Answer (score 2):

The '1010' should be "1010" (double quotes).  A single quote is used for a character literal (a single character).

Comment: Then i get this error; Parameter o of mode out can not be associated with a formal parameter of mode in.

Comment: Would it be because of i did not use parameter o inside process() ? Also, can i put o inside process, since it is an output?

Answer (score 2):

So you have fixed the first error as per Mark's answer.

The second error is that you can not make use of the value of an output.

```
if output = "0101";    -- illegal

some_signal <= output; -- illegal
```

To solve this you need to create an internal signal (say sum). You then use the internal signal, and assign it to the external signal.

```
architecture Behavioral of binary_add is

signal sum : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

process(n1, n2, sum) 
begin

sum <= n1 + n2;

if( sum = '1010') then 
bool <= '1';
else
bool <= '0';
end if;

end process;

o <= sum;

end Behavioral;
```